# Why do I see a red cross over index.jsp?

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

I have set the `jdk compliance` level to *1.7* and the JRE version I am using is also set to *1.7*.

But I am getting a red cross on `index.jsp`. What could be the reason for this ?

[image]

Though I can see the file running in the browser, eclipse's console doesn't show any error.

Comment: First make sure there really are no errors: *Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Markers*. If there are none, sometimes Eclipse gets stuck thinking there are errors when there aren't. Close all editors, clean the project, *close* then *reopen* it in the project explorer (right-click on it), and see if the error clears. I've also noticed that Eclipse has weird issues parsing JSP; sometimes it's confused and you just have to ignore it, but you could try opening the JSP file, selecting all, cutting, then pasting to force a recheck (or sometimes cut -> clean build -> paste).

Comment: @JasonC Consider, posting this an answer

Comment: Does it show you anything when you actually open the file? *Are* there any entries in the Markers or Errors Views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure there really are no errors: *Window -> Show View -> Other... -> Markers*.

If there are none, sometimes Eclipse gets stuck thinking there are errors when there aren't. Close all editors, clean the project, *close* then *reopen* it in the project explorer (right-click on it), and see if the error clears.

I've also noticed that Eclipse has weird issues parsing JSP; sometimes it's confused and you just have to ignore it, but you could try opening the JSP file, selecting all, cutting, then pasting to force a recheck (or sometimes cut -> clean build -> paste).

I don't know why it does this, and I've been reading / filing bug reports for literally years, but it really seems to choke on JSP (something about the mix of HTML, Java, and JSP tags doesn't sit right with its parser).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse marks with this sign any file containing syntax errors (not compiling). If you don't have any syntax errors, then you should try cleaning up all your projects, as sometimes it may look inside old metadata files to determine whether there are errors in a given file.